# Bash: How do I delete all my textfiles starting with #?

Tags: bash

I tried

```
rm -r #*
```

and

```
rm #*
```

But it just outputs this message:
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file

What's the problem?

Comment: This should be at Super User, but escape it `rm \#*`  # starts a comment

Comment: Can you please clarify, do the file**names** start with `#` or do the file contents start with a `#`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rm \#*
```

should do the trick for you. Remember # has got special meaning in the shell, it starts a comment.

To quote

> Lines beginning with a # (with the exception of #!) are comments and
>   will not be executed.
>   Comments may also occur following the end of a command.

&

> escape [backslash]. A quoting mechanism for single characters.
>
> \X escapes the character X. This has the effect of "quoting" X,
>   equivalent to 'X'. The \ may be used to quote " and ', so they are
>   expressed literally.

Had you have files `'file1`,`'file2` & `'file3`, to delete them you would have used :

```
rm \'file* #Comment : This deletes all the files starting with 'file
```

**Reference:**[TLDP note on special characters](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html)

Answer (score 4):

`#` is a shell comment. You'll need to quote it, like so:

```
rm '#'*
```

Note that the hash is in quotes and the glob is outside the quotes.

Comment: I did rm '#' * and it says No Such File or Directory.

Comment: Then I did rm '#'* (without the space) and it said the same thing but this time deleted all the files in my directory, whether or not it started with a #

Comment: It was the first one that deleted all your files, when you added a space it tried to delete a file call `#` and then the `*` was expanded to all the filenames in the current directory.

Answer (score -2):

This command will list all the file starting with `#` and feed them to `rm`:

```
ls . |grep "^#.*" |xargs rm -rf
```