# What is wrong in following approach (rm + xargs)

Tags: linux, bash, grep, xargs, rm

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in following way of file deletion which starts with "#".

Files in directory :

```
ola@ola:~/.scratch/hmm$ ls
five  #four  #one  six  #three  #two
ola@ola:~/.scratch/hmm$

ola@ola:~/.scratch/hmm$ ls . |grep "#.*" |xargs rm -rf
ola@ola:~/.scratch/hmm$ ls
five  six
ola@ola:~/.scratch/hmm$
```

Ps : Asking in reference of following question

[Bash: How do I delete all my textfiles starting with #?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986721/bash-how-do-i-delete-all-my-textfiles-starting-with)

Comment: Why do you need `ls` and `grep`. It can be just `rm -- ./#*`

Comment: You can see my similar comment on your earlier question also

Comment: I did and I liked yours more as it is simple, I wanted to know if anything wrong in this ...As I am not very much familiar with xargs so I want to know if   xargs is rightly used or just by coincidence I am getting desired results.

Comment: Your command will work but is error prone as filenames can contain whitespace characters in Unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls` might list the files in several columns, and your regexp is not anchored to the beginning of the filename, either. Filenames containing whitespace will also be problematic.

Comment: ahh, now I got it.  It could delete any file which have # in between. 

Following should be better 

 ls . |grep "^#.*" |xargs rm -rf

Comment: Better, but still not good enough. At the very least, you also need to say `ls -1`.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs `ls` defaults to one column if its standard output is not a terminal.

Comment: The BSD man page, at least, mentions it in the entry for `-1`. The POSIX spec also mandates it: "The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the -C, -m, or -x options is specified. If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined."